# How to make multiple rows from one row in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have data that looks like this:

```
Name | Address | FormName
John | 123 Apple Drive | Form1 Form2 Form3
Dave| 133 Westchester Drive | Form1 Form2 Form3
```

How can I turn this into multiple rows based on that `FormName` column? So the result would be:

```
Name | Address | FormName
John | 123 Apple Drive | Form1
John | 123 Apple Drive | Form2
John | 123 Apple Drive | Form3
Dave| 133 Westchester Drive | Form1 
Dave| 133 Westchester Drive | Form2
Dave| 133 Westchester Drive | Form3
```

So a row was created for each form for each person.

I tried using the `tJavaFlex` component but that seems too complicated for this simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `tNormalize` does exactly this! I hooked up `tNormalize` to my `tMap` like this:
[image: img1]

And in `tNormalize` component I specified what I wanted to separate on (spaces) and what column to normalize[image]

Answer (score -1):

One approach:

1. Loop for each row in the data set.

1.1. Put the name and address into a "current person" string.

1.2. When you get to the form "field", parse that.

1.2.1. For each form in the form field

1.2.2. Print (add to vector, etc.) the "current person" + "current form" - Concatenate.

It's a very basic, straight forward approach, so get that first, understand how it works, then consider other approaches - if any.